# SetPropertyListener Problem when using with af:commandButton in oracle adf

Tags: oracle-adf, jdeveloper

Hi     I want to set a pageflowScope using setPropertyListener and when I use that in h:commandButton it works but when I use that in af:commandButton and when I hit the button it does not work but the second time I hit the button it works  ...  when I hit the button at the first time it should put the method result into a pageflowScope variable but it always do that in the second click ... I don't know why

here is my code

```
  <af:panelFormLayout id="pfl2">
                            <af:inputText value="#{bindings.usrname.inputValue}" label="نام کاربری"
                                          required="#{bindings.usrname.hints.mandatory}"
                                          columns="#{bindings.usrname.hints.displayWidth}"
                                          maximumLength="#{bindings.usrname.hints.precision}"
                                          shortDesc="#{bindings.usrname.hints.tooltip}" id="it1">
                                <f:validator binding="#{bindings.usrname.validator}"/>
                            </af:inputText>
                            <af:inputText value="#{bindings.passwrd.inputValue}" label="رمزعبور"
                                          required="#{bindings.passwrd.hints.mandatory}"
                                          columns="#{bindings.passwrd.hints.displayWidth}"
                                          maximumLength="#{bindings.passwrd.hints.precision}"
                                          shortDesc="#{bindings.passwrd.hints.tooltip}" id="it2">
                                <f:validator binding="#{bindings.passwrd.validator}"/>
                            </af:inputText>
                            <af:button actionListener="#{bindings.execPLSQLProcedure.execute}" text="execPLSQLProcedure"
                                       disabled="#{!bindings.execPLSQLProcedure.enabled}" id="b1">
                                <af:setPropertyListener from="#{bindings['return'].inputValue}"
                                                        to="#{pageFlowScope.Result}" type="action"/>
                            </af:button>
                        </af:panelFormLayout>
```

how can I fix it or please tell me an alternative way ...thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you have to click two times for the action to trigger it is because on your first click your form hit data validation issues.

1) If you don't see it, you first need to add a partialTrigger to your button :

```
<af:commandButton partialTriggers="pfl2" partialSubmit="true" actionListener="#{bindings.execPLSQLProcedure.execute}" text="execPLSQLProcedure" disabled="#{!bindings.execPLSQLProcedure.enabled}" id="b1" >
    <af:setPropertyListener from="#{bindings['return'].inputValue}" to="#{pageFlowScope.Result}" type="action"/>
</af:button>
```

> whether the action should be done through a partial page submit or
>   not. Default is false: no partial page submit; the full page will be
>   refreshed. When set to true, the full page will not be refreshed. To
>   re-render specific components on your page in response to the partial
>   page submit, you have to tell ADF Faces. The easiest way to do this is
>   with the partialTriggers attribute.

2) If you want to bypass validation you can also add an immediate="true" attribute. **In your case it doesn't look like you should as you want to validate the password length and requirement. See 1)**

```
<af:commandButton immediate="true" partialTriggers="pfl2" partialSubmit="true" actionListener="#{bindings.execPLSQLProcedure.execute}" text="execPLSQLProcedure" disabled="#{!bindings.execPLSQLProcedure.enabled}" id="b1" >
    <af:setPropertyListener from="#{bindings['return'].inputValue}" to="#{pageFlowScope.Result}" type="action"/>
</af:button>
```

see docs : https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E12839_01/apirefs.1111/e12419/tagdoc/af_commandButton.html

> whether data validation - client-side or server-side - will be skipped
>   when events are generated by this component. When immediate is true,
>   the command's action and ActionListeners, including the default
>   ActionListener provided by the JavaServer Faces implementation, will
>   be executed during Apply Request Values phase of the request
>   processing lifecycle, rather than waiting until the Invoke Application
>   phase. Because validation runs during Process Validators (after Apply
>   Request Values, but before Invoke Application), setting immediate to
>   true will skip validation.

Comment: it gave me the same  result ...  I create a textbox that shows the value of PageScope.Result on that page but the first hit  didn't show anything ... Am I missing something ? .... and then I turned Immediate to true then After any clicking it did  not show anything

Comment: You need to add a partialTrigger to the button with a target to the parent component of your textbox. This will refresh the textbox and display the new value when you click on the button.

Comment: I did that too ... It seems like when I click first It just start to listen  then after second time it will work

Comment: is the SetpropertyListener type correct? ..  the type of that is action

Comment: Yes this is due to the data validation, see the second point.

Comment: I did that two ... I changed it to  immediate then It did not happen

Comment: Have you tried the SetpropertyListener before ?? ... if U have Can I have a sample for that?  ... because I really need that to be done ... or IF any alternative way  is available for setting the pageflowscope value please Tell me  ...  thank you  soo much